# How to stop white background when I fadeIn() container Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a windows phone app in visual studio using the Web View.

On the click of a button, I delete the html elements on the page, create new ones and also change the background image of the container element. I fade everything in using the `fadeIn()` method. However, when the container is fading in, there is a flash of a white background. I've tried changing the background color and I've also set the body to have a background-images in the hope that you would see that, but it didn't work.

Ideally what I'd like is for a new background to fade in seamlessly. I was thinking I could have the body background and the container background have the same image and then hid the container, change the background image and then fade it in again. This doesn't seem to work.

JSfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/nva1LLzh/2/

```
function startPage() {
    //Add start button when game hasn't started
    $('<div class="startButton">Start Saving</div>').hide().appendTo(".container").fadeIn(1000);
    //$(".container").append('<div class="startButton">Start Saving</div>').fadeIn("slow");
    $(".startButton").click(function () {
        $(".startButton").remove();
        maxCanSave();
    });
}

function maxCanSave() {
    $('.container').css('background-image', 'url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/fa/c3/d9/fac3d9517be53c025fbb494440369934.jpg)');
    $(".container").hide().fadeIn(2000);
    $('<h1>How Much?</h1>').hide().appendTo(".container").fadeIn(2000);
    $('<p>How much money do you want to save?</p>').hide().appendTo(".container").fadeIn(2000);
    $('<input type="text" name="firstname" value="Enter Amount">').hide().appendTo(".container").fadeIn(2000);
    $('<div class="startButton">Continue?</div>').hide().appendTo(".container").fadeIn(2000);
    $(".startButton").click(function () {
        $(".container").empty();
        showDate();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your updated fiddle: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uwpwfm1f/)**

You can add a new dummy container with the initial background and fade it out to reveal the new background like this:

```
<div class="container"> /* contains new background */
    <div class='dummy-container'></div> /* contains old background */
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir! And thanks everyone else for the help!

Comment: Sorry to bring it up again but I'm just wondering how would you go about it if you want to do this more than once? I was hoping to change the background on each button click for example - however, with your solution it seems to only work once as I can't fade the container out without fading the dummy-container aswell. You can see here in this JSFiddle what i mean. After you click the button again I want to change the background in the showDate() function but it doesn't seem to work. http://jsfiddle.net/uwpwfm1f/1/

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for this? http://jsfiddle.net/nva1LLzh/4/

It is realised with `fadeOut()`s callback function in `maxCanSave()`

Comment: That is exactly what I'm look for except for the white background between the fade. Is there any way to have it fade directly to another image - or at least change the background color to be black? I was hoping that the background image of the body would be visible when you fade out the container.

Comment: whis white blink is caused because image is loading at the line `$('.container').css('background-image', 'url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/fa/c3/d9/fac3d9517be53c025fbb494440369934.jpg)');`. u can make it better for adding 2 classes in css styles with different images and switching tham between fades

Comment: Is this what you meant? http://jsfiddle.net/nva1LLzh/6/ 

I'm still getting the same problem. Maybe I'm not understanding you correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Evt has answered this already, but an alternative approach would be to separate the background from the container-class:

```
<div class ="bg-container">
    <div class="container">
```

And do something like this in the CSS:

```
.bg-container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/c0/10/40/c010401ca403a4e02aae87459bfb298e.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat; }
```

Here's a working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/nva1LLzh/5/). I bugged it out, but hopefully it's enough to illustrate what I'm getting at.